# hadoop distcp via java resulting in NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run a `distcp` command on my hadoop cluster using the Hadoop Java Library to move content from the HDFS to a Google Cloud Bucket. I am getting the error `NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem`

Below is my java code:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp;
import org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCpOptions;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HadoopHelper {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HadoopHelper.class);

    private static final String FS_DEFAULT_FS = "fs.defaultFS";

    private final Configuration conf;

    public HadoopHelper(String hadoopUrl) {
        conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set(FS_DEFAULT_FS, "hdfs://" + hadoopUrl);
    }

    public void distCP(JsonArray files, String target) {

        try {
            List<Path> srcPaths = new ArrayList<>();

            for (JsonElement file : files) {
                String srcPath = file.getAsString();
                srcPaths.add(new Path(srcPath));
            }

            DistCpOptions options = new DistCpOptions.Builder(
                    srcPaths,
                    new Path("gs://" + target)
            ).build();

            logger.info("Using distcp to copy {} to gs://{}", files, target);

            this.conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem");
            this.conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.email", "my-svc-account@my-gcp-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
            this.conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.keyfile", "config/my-svc-account-keyfile.p12");
            this.conf.set("fs.gs.project.id", "my-gcp-project");


            DistCp distCp = new DistCp(this.conf, options);
            Job job = distCp.execute();

            job.waitForCompletion(true);

            logger.info("Distcp operation success. Exiting");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while trying to execute distcp", e);
            logger.error("Distcp operation failed. Exiting");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Distcp failed");
        }
    }

    public void createDirectory() throws IOException {
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(this.conf);
        fileSystem.mkdirs(new Path("/user/newfolder"));
        logger.info("Done");
    }
}
```

I have added the below dependencies in the `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-distcp</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
        <version>hadoop3-2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
        <artifactId>util</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

If I run the distcp command on the cluster itself like so: `hadoop distcp /user gs://my_bucket_name/`

The distcp operation works and the content is copied onto the Cloud Bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the jar to the hadoop's classpath?

> Add the connector jar to Hadoop's classpath
> Placing the connector jar in the HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_JARS_DIR directory should be sufficient to have Hadoop load the jar. Alternatively, to be certain that the jar is loaded, you can add HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:</path/to/gcs-connector.jar> to hadoop-env.sh in the Hadoop configuration directory.

This needs to be done to DisctCp conf(in your code `this.conf`) before this line of code:

```
this.conf.set("HADOOP_CLASSPATH","$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/tmp/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar")
DistCp distCp = new DistCp(this.conf, options);
```

If it helps there is a [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md) for this.

Comment: I added hadoop libraries as a pom dependency. Is this sufficient?

Comment: I would think that it's not sufficient. But you can easily test this out.

Comment: Yeah I get the above error when I run the application having the hadoop libraries in my classpath. So I dont think it is enough. What else should I add to my classpath?

Comment: I'm confused did you add it to your hadoop class path as stated in my answer or your jar's class path? (pom.xml)  I'm suggesting it should be added to the hadoop class path.

Comment: I have added it to my application's pom.xml as well as the classpath of my cluster, if that is what you meant? If I run `hadoop distcp /user gs://my_bucket_name/` on the cluster, the distcp operation works.

Comment: You need to setup DistCp.conf in your code, to have that jar as part of it's Hadoop_Classpath.  It's not sufficient to just have the jar in your POM. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by DistCp.conf? Is it another downloadable jar? Do I need to add it to `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH` of my cluster or should I have it on the classpath of my application?

Comment: I updated my answer so hopefully it's a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks I understood your explanation. Issue is, I have already added the gcs connector jar to `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. I can confirm this because when I run the command `hadoop distcp /user gs://my_bucket_name/ ` on my cluster the distcp operation works.

Comment: I totally understand that.  But it's clear from your error message that the distCp in your code does not know about the library.  And I'm saying that you should set $HADOOP_CLASSPATH in the code version of DistCp by editing the conf object that you are passing it and editing the configuration so it's aware of it.

Comment: I've edited my code to make it clearer.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Just one more thing before I try it out, the path you specified in your example `/tmp/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar` is this a path on the namenode or a worker node? Or is it a path on the machine that is running my Java application? In my example, the Java example will run on a separate server & not on the namenode/worker node

Comment: The path is to where it is on the server that you are running the code from.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a bunch Matt! Its a bit late where I am at right now but hopefully in 8-9 hours I will be back at work & will try out the code and let you know.

Comment: Did it resolve the issue? I am stuck with same issue.